# How to separate edges detected by Canny

Tags: c, canny-operator

I have tried `cvFindContours` function in OpenCV to get separate edges after Canny-edge-dectcting.

My question is how to do the same thing as `cvFindcontours` does by myself. Better implemented in C code.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In opencv documentation, it is mentioned that the algorithm of the following paper is implemented in `cvFindcontours`

```
Suzuki, S. and Abe, K., Topological Structural Analysis of Digitized Binary Images by Border Following. CVGIP 30 1, pp 32-46 (1985)
```